# intellectual and intelligent

Tags: word-choice

What does one mean if he says he is intellectual but not intelligent?

What does one mean if he says he is intelligent but not intellectual?

Does being intellectual imply being intelligent?

Does being intelligent imply being intellectual?

Comment: This is general reference

Answer (score 2):

*What does one mean if he says he is intellectual but not intelligent?* you can meet many people like that, who are attracted by intellectual outputs, say modern physics theories, but who fail to grasp the consequences, the essential parts, what matters and what not (let's not start a theory of intelligence here!)

*What does one mean if he says he is intelligent but not intellectual?* Intelligence for example as ways of optimising a course of action, can be applied everywhere. An athlete will display intelligence and therefore could be said to be intelligent if he trains in a proper way, similarly a career oriented person if she knows how to networl. In both case their intelligence can be detached to any interest in intellectual outputs (science, literature, culture, etc).

*Does being intellectual imply being intelligent?* No, see first answer.

*Does being intelligent imply being intellectual?* No, see second answer.

To summarise an intellectual person will orient her intelligence towards the understanding of intellectual outputs rather than other activities not involving the intellect, and apply to it whatever her intelligence may be.